# How can I set a different action for a Tabbed Activity

Tags: android

So I made a new tabbed activity, made the three fragments and their xmls , put everything straight , everything is working , and once i wanted to work on the floating action button, I didn't know how to do , basically I'm Trying to show a different dialog when you click  on the different floating action buttons , you all know that each Tab has its own Floating action button, I couldn't find where to set the action that I'm needing!! 
Please Answer Me, Thanks

Comment: Showing what you have so far, with code and screenshots, will help people to answer your question correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each tab doesn't necessarily have a different floating action button. There can be many different ways to do different things with fab on different tabs. You can define one fab in MainActivity of your app and override the methode onPageChangeListener() of your viewpager like this.

```
//In MainActivity's onCreate()
int fabState = 0;
FloatingActionButton fab;

//In onCreate method instantiate fab by using findViewById
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewBtId(R.id.your_fab_id);

viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
   //Called when the scroll state changes.
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int position, 
    float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
   //This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
   fabState = position;
  }};

fab.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener(){

if(fabState==0){
//write actions related to page one
}
else if(fabState ==1 ){
//write actions related to page two
}
else if(fabState==2){
//write actions related to page three
}
else{}

});
```

So, this way by declaring a variable named fabState you can store on which page of viewpager you are and hence make use of one single fab rather than declaring multiple fabs one for each fragment. The above fab will be declared in activity_main.xml and not in some fragment's layout file..

Comment: thank you , and what what should i do if i have 3 fragments layouts and 3 java classes? and i intend to write actions for those three floating actions buttons, i hope you understood me ..

Comment: @NefissaKhedher The above code is for the same. Your ViewPager will change pages(fragments) and this code tracks changes as of which fragment is on display at the moment. If you don't know anything about viewpager, I would recommend you going through [this guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter) :)

Comment: So i've tried to do it : and he crossed the setOnPageChangeListener , so i've changed it to addOnPageChangeListener , but then when i tried to do the fab.setOnClickListener it wouldn't resolve it, Can you please help me?

Comment: @NefissaKhedher my code isn't complete. I can not write whole code for you. If you are a beginner then you must not jump to such programs. Anyhow, you have to declare the fab in MainActivity. I will edit my post.

Comment: I suggest if you have just started with android development then try going through [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) step by step. This will surely help you :)